# Retrieve a record that has 2 specific features in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following database of pictures (a picture can have multiple features):

```
Table Picture
-------------
ID     Name

1      Mona Lisa
2      Scream


Table Features
-------------
ID     Name        PictureID (FK to Picture)

1      Portrait    2
2      Expressive  2
3      Big         2
4      Small       1
5      Expressive  1
5      Big         1
```

I'd wish to do a query that retrieves all the Pictures that are a Portrait AND Big, (so the result would be in this case "Scream"). I've come up with this query to retrieve it, but I'm not sure if it is the prettiest and most efficient way to do it. Here's my proposal:

```
SELECT *
FROM Picture o
WHERE
(select count(*)
from Feature c
where o.id = c.pictureID and c.Name like '%Portrait%') >= 1
AND
(select count(*)
from Feature c
where o.id = c.pictureID and c.Name like '%Big%') >= 1
```

In this case, I have to go through the Features table twice (which, to my personal taste, I find it "ugly").

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT picture.name FROM picture 
JOIN features 
on picture.id=features.pictureID
WHERE features.name IN('Portrait','Big')
GROUP BY features.pictureID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT features.ID)>=2
```

Comment: Your answer works as expected, but I'd wish to know (just for curiosity): what about if I want to scale up to a third property? I mean, having a numeral in a query and having to change 2 parts of a query to extend it to more properties is something I'm somewhat reluctant to do.

Comment: `WHERE name IN('blah','ba','buh').... HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT features.ID)>=3` I dont know a way without changing the query in 2 parts but why is this such a problem?